# Running TX433 and RX433 RF modules with AVR microcontrollers

Tags: c++, c, macros, atmega

I am trying to interface an RF module with AVR ATmega 128.
I found [this code](http://winavr.scienceprog.com/example-avr-projects/running-tx433-and-rx433-rf-modules-with-avr-microcontrollers.html) interesting, but I couldn't understand these two lines:

```
//define receive parameters

#define SYNC 0XAA// synchro signal

#define RADDR 0x44
```

Comment: Seeing the code you have linked, it looks like those two defines are not related at all to the library/interface you are using, but are rather using only in the example code. Then this is purely C/C++ question. I'm adding relevant tags. You should consider rewording your question. If you are not sure about the actual value, you should better update your question with their actual use (i.e. reference to library API, where these are used).

Comment: 0xAA is 10101010b in binary, an alternating sequence of 1s and 0s. This is sometimes used at the start of an RF transmission, especially with cheap AM transceivers, to allow the RF receiver at the other end to detect and adjust to the starting transmission (but is otherwise ignored); in your case it may actually be this kind of synchronization pattern.

Comment: Looking at the liked page seems to confirm my assumption: "4 byte data packages in order to send one byte information. These include:   one dummy synchronization byte (10101010);" - Besides, the transmitter and receiver shown are obviously of the "cheap AM"-kind I was referring to above :) - And on a side note: This kind of receiver will be unable to reproduce prolonged sequences of only 1s or only 0s, which may have to be accomodated for in software.

Answer (score 1):

Without other information, I'll think you're using C or some C-like language.

`define` creates a so called macro, this means in your code every reference to `SYNC` for example is replaced by `0XAA`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for replying. it's  AVR-GCC question. I just want to know if i can choose any adress for sync and RADDR . thank you

Answer (score 1):

The page moved to:
[https://scienceprog.com/running-tx433-and-rx433-rf-modules-with-avr-microcontrollers/][1]

There are better ways to encode data to avoid losing synchronization. The best known is Non-return to zero (NRZ). Also, check out Biphase encoding.